# Operations on distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, simulation

Say we have two r.v X and Y which are independent and differently distributed ( for e.g X follows a bell curve and Y  follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda > 0$

What are the different  methods to numerically compute the distribution X+Y, X*Y, X/Y, min(X,Y) etc...?

I read about Mellin transform and Monte-Carlo simulation but it seemed to me that since these methods go back to a long time ago, there must be something that already exists for such operations within a library or a module on a programming language like Matlab or R (or any other platform)

Any ideas|suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Almost all numerical probability problems have to fall under some monte carlo algorithm at some point, but for nice distributions, the answer suggested is the way to go. Half of the battle is just posing the problem intelligently, which is what the answer of fgp does.

Answer (score 3):

If $X,Y$ are independent and have distribution function $F_X,F_Y$ and densities $f_X$,$f_Y$, you have $$\begin{eqnarray}
  &P(X+Y \leq z) &=& \int_{x+y \leq z} f_X(x) f_Y(y) \,d(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_X(x) f_Y(y) \,dy \,dx \\
 &&=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) F_Y(z-x) \,dx \text{,} \\
  &f_{X+Y}(z) &=& \frac{d}{dz}P(X+Y \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(z-x)\,dx \\
\text{ and } \\ \\
  &P(\min\{X,Y\} \leq z) &=& P(X \leq z \text{ or } Y \leq z) = F_X(z) + F_Y(z) - F_X(z)F_Y(z) \text{,} \\
  &f_{\min X,Y}(z) &=&  f_X(z) + f_Y(z) - f_X(z)F_Y(z) - F_X(z)f_Y(z)  \\\text{ respectively } \\ \\
  &P(\max\{X,Y\} \leq z) &=& F_X(z)F_Y(z) \text{,} \\
  &f_{\max X,Y}(z) &=& f_X(z)F_Y(z) + F_X(z)f_Y(z) \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
For $XY$ and $X/Y$ there are similar transformation formulas, and you can always evaluate the resulting integrals numerically. For $X+Y$, using that $f_{X+Y}$ is the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$ might help.

Comment: This wasn't my question. I am asking about existing methods/tools on Matlab or R (or others) that can perform these kind of operations numerically. I don't think that the implementation of such a tool  is easy task. I am presuming that some existing libraries are already doing it. Any thought? or references for at least some algorithms that could help?

Comment: @aflous This site is about math itself, not about MATLAB/R/whatever....

Comment: I know but I thought that some numerical analysts might use this forum as well, in which case they would know about such tools

Comment: @aflous Yes, but since your comment clearly indicates that you're only interested in a ready-made solution, you're on the wrong site. And, if I might say so, your question leaves something ot be desired in any case. You don't tell us in which *form* the distributions of $X$,$Y$ are given - do we have an expression for the PDF? The CDF? Are these evaluated on some grid? How do expect a "Use this and that R command" type of answer without telling us that?

Comment: okay my bad :( I'll edit my question in few minutes then (do you know a better website for this question? programmers.stackexchange doesn't seem suitable for me..

Comment: It would be good to note that $X+Y$ has a density which is the convolution of the densities of $X$ and $Y$. Also, $P(min(X,Y) \leq z) = P( \{X \leq z\} \cup \{Y \leq z\}) = P(X \leq z) + P(Y \leq z) - P(X \leq z \text{ and } Y \leq z) = F_X(z)+F_Y(z)-F_x(z) F_y(z)$. (The comment is rendering a bit weird, but I'm sure people get the point.) But $P(max(X,Y) \leq z) = P(X \leq z, Y \leq z) = F_X(z) F_Y(z)$.

Comment: @Batman Uh, you're right of course, will fix!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mathematica for such calculations. 
For example TransformedDistribution[] can help you solve the problem if it can be solved in closed form at all.